# Can a User join multiple video channels simultaneously in Agora Unity SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I am using Agora Unity SDK and I have a game that has multiple tables (channels ids)a user can play a game with up to four tables simultaneously and all tables have video integration. I want to know that can we join multiple tables and use the features of SDK on all tables simultaneously.

Comment: Have you simply tried?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may join multiple channels starting from Video SDK version 3.0.1 and up.  Please take a look at the sample project at [the Unity QuickStart Github repo](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Unity-Quickstart/tree/master/API-Example-Unity).